# Android test coverage report for multi module app

Tags: android, unit-testing, automated-tests, integration-testing, android-espresso

We have a multi module application. Where we have 3 library projects and 1 launch project.

module1 (Libraray)
module2 (Libraray) depends on module1
module3 (Libraray)depends on module1

Launch (Does not have any source code its just a launcher for all lib)depends on module1 and module 2.

In module1 we are accessing module 2 and module 3 classes using facade pattern. Due to that we need to write all the test cases in Launch project as we have access the to all the classes in launch project so that we have access to all the classes and test cases will not fail due to NoClassDefException.

When we write the test cases in Launch project then we are able to run the test cases and we are getting the execution report as 100% and it create a index.html file with all the details of test cases but when i try to generate the coverage report then it not showing any data for coverage report. Below is my gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"`

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.test.mobile"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 17
    multiDexEnabled true
    testApplicationId "com.test.mobile.test"
    testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

buildTypes {

    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
    }

    debug{
        testCoverageEnabled true
    }
}


dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
    javaMaxHeapSize "4096M"
    jumboMode = true
    incremental false
}

afterEvaluate {
    tasks.matching {
        it.name.startsWith('dex')
    }.each { dx ->
        if (dx.additionalParameters == null) {
            dx.additionalParameters = []
        }
        dx.additionalParameters += '--multi-dex'
        dx.additionalParameters += "--main-dex-list=$projectDir\\multidex-main-dex-list.txt".toString()
    }
}}
dependencies {
compile project(':module2')
compile project(':module3')
compile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:2.2.1"

// Dependencies for local unit tests
testCompile "junit:junit:4.12" exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'

testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-all:1.10.19" exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
testCompile "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3" exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.2" exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.2" exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'


// Android Testing Support Library's runner and rules
androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test:runner:0.4.1"  exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test:rules:0.4.1" exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'

// Espresso UI Testing dependencies.
androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1" exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs' exclude group: 'javax.annotation' exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations' exclude module: 'javax.annotation-api'
androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.1" exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs' exclude group: 'javax.annotation' exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations' exclude module: 'javax.annotation-api' exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2.1" exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs' exclude group: 'javax.annotation' exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations' exclude module: 'javax.annotation-api'}
```

`task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: 'testDebugUnitTest') {
    def projects = new ArrayList()
    subprojects.each { prj ->
        projects.add(prj)
    }`

```
reports {
    xml.enabled = true
    html.enabled = true
}

jacocoClasspath = configurations['androidJacocoAnt']

def fileFilter = ['**/R.class', '**/R$*.class', '**/BuildConfig.*', '**/Manifest*.*', '**/*Test*.*', 'android/**/*.*']
def debugTree = fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/intermediates/classes/debug", excludes: fileFilter)
def mainSrc = "${project.projectDir}/src/main/java"

sourceDirectories = files([mainSrc])
classDirectories = files([debugTree])
/*sourceDirectories = generateSourceFiles(projects)
classDirectories = generateClassDirs(projects)*/

executionData = files(["${buildDir}/jacoco/testDebugUnitTest.exec",
                       "${buildDir}/outputs/code-coverage/connected/coverage.ec"
])}
```

Comment: Do you have similar changes in `build.gradle` for libraries?

Comment: Other below is the one of the lib project build.gradle.
`android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 17
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

   

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
    }
}`
Test cases information is not available in lib projects

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what we had in our top `build.gradle` for generating HTML coverage reports:

```
def coverageSourceDirs = ['app/src/main/java', 'core/src/main/java', 'database/src/main/java']

def coverageExcludes = ['**/R.class',
                        '**/R$*.class',
                        '**/*$$ViewBinder*.*',
                        '**/inject/*',
                        '**/*$InjectAdapter.*',
                        '**/BuildConfig.*',
                        '**/Manifest*.*',
                        '**/Dagger*.*',
                        '**/*_Provide*Factory.*',
                        '**/*_Member*Injector.*',
                        '**/*_Factory.*']

def coverageClassDirectories = [fileTree(dir: 'app/build/intermediates/classes/debug', excludes: coverageExcludes),
                                fileTree(dir: 'core/build/intermediates/classes/debug', excludes: coverageExcludes),
                                fileTree(dir: 'database/build/intermediates/classes/debug', excludes: coverageExcludes)]

task jacocoRootReport(type: JacocoReport) {
    dependsOn "app:jacocoTestReport",
            "core:jacocoTestReport",
            "database:jacocoTestReport"

    additionalSourceDirs = files(coverageSourceDirs)
    sourceDirectories = files(coverageSourceDirs)
    classDirectories = files(coverageClassDirectories)
    executionData = files(tasks.getByPath("app:jacocoTestReport").executionData,
            tasks.getByPath("core:jacocoTestReport").executionData,
            tasks.getByPath("database:jacocoTestReport").executionData    
)

    reports {
        html.enabled = true
        xml.enabled = false
        csv.enabled = false
    }
    onlyIf = {
        true
    }

    doFirst {
        executionData = files(executionData.findAll {
            it.exists()
        })
    }
}
```

And in every submodule:

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        debug {
            testCoverageEnabled = true
        }
    }
}

def coverageSourceDirs = ['src/main/java']

task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: "testJenkinsUnitTest") {
    group = "Reporting"

    description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports"

    classDirectories = fileTree(dir: 'build/intermediates/classes/debug',
            excludes: ['**/R.class',
                       '**/R$*.class',
                       '**/*$$ViewBinder*.*',
                       '**/inject/*',
                       '**/*$InjectAdapter.*',
                       '**/BuildConfig.*',
                       '**/Manifest*.*',
                       '**/Dagger*.*',
                       '**/*_Provide*Factory.*',
                       '**/*_Member*Injector.*',
                       '**/*_Factory.*',
                       '**/PagerTitleStripV22*.*'])

    additionalSourceDirs = files(coverageSourceDirs)
    sourceDirectories = files(coverageSourceDirs)
    executionData = files('build/jacoco/testDebugUnitTest.exec')

    doFirst {
        new File("$buildDir/intermediates/classes/").eachFileRecurse { file ->
            if (file.name.contains('$$')) {
                file.renameTo(file.path.replace('$$', '$'))
            }
        }
    }

    reports {
        xml.enabled = false
        html.enabled = true
    }
}
```

Note that you don't need it if you do coverage analyse with Jenkins plugin or Sonar.

P.S. if you have any problems please check all paths manually, I might mistype something. It is really a pain to setup it

Comment: Do you have test cases in all your modules only only in main modules. 
In our case we have a module which contains all the test cases for all modules(app,core, database). And in that module we don't have any source code.

Comment: I don't think tests should be separate module :) And we have tests as part of libraries. But this should be not a problem, the main path to classes, sources and result of coverage should be set correctly

Comment: HI Thanks a lot for your support. 
I have updated the test project which simulates our problem in github. 

https://github.com/HariSoni87/codecoveragetest/tree/master/junittest_coverage_launch

Could you please look into the project and let us know where we are going wrong. We have done lot of changes which doesn't seems to work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your repo, I haven't included Jacoco yet but I had a lot of pain making `androidTest`s works il a multi-module project (troubles with code generation and jar merging), this really helped me

Answer (score 9):

I have 3 modules named with gcm_demo, googleservices and networkcommunication
so under build.gradle of each module
write

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: ['testDebugUnitTest', 'createDebugCoverageReport']) {
reports {
    xml.enabled = true
    html.enabled = true
}

def fileFilter = ['**/R.class', '**/R$*.class', '**/BuildConfig.*', '**/Manifest*.*', '**/*Test*.*', 'android/**/*.*']
def debugTree = fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/intermediates/classes/debug", excludes: fileFilter)
def mainSrc = "${project.projectDir}/src/main/java"

sourceDirectories = files([mainSrc])
classDirectories = files([debugTree])
executionData = fileTree(dir: "$buildDir", includes: [
        "jacoco/testDebugUnitTest.exec", "outputs/code-coverage/connected/*coverage.ec"
])
}
```

Now in Project build.gradle write the following scrpit

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
task jacocoRootReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: ['gcm_demo:jacocoTestReport', 'googleservice:jacocoTestReport', 'networkcommunication:jacocoTestReport']) {
reports {
    xml.enabled = true
    html.enabled = true
}
sourceDirectories = files([tasks.getByPath("gcm_demo:jacocoTestReport").sourceDirectories,
                           tasks.getByPath("googleservice:jacocoTestReport").sourceDirectories,
                           tasks.getByPath("networkcommunication:jacocoTestReport").sourceDirectories])

classDirectories = files([tasks.getByPath("gcm_demo:jacocoTestReport").classDirectories,
                          tasks.getByPath("googleservice:jacocoTestReport").classDirectories,
                          tasks.getByPath("networkcommunication:jacocoTestReport").classDirectories])

executionData = files([tasks.getByPath("gcm_demo:jacocoTestReport").executionData,
                       tasks.getByPath("googleservice:jacocoTestReport").executionData,
                       tasks.getByPath("networkcommunication:jacocoTestReport").executionData])

}
```

for execution use

```
gradlew clean jRR (short abbreviation)
```

after build successful output folder is

```
{project location}\build\reports\jacoco\jacocoRootReport\html\index.html
```

it provides the full project coverage of UI and unitTest

Comment: I can still see only my app modules packages in coverage reports... I am not able to find the submodules package in coverage report.. Can you please elaborate how to do this?

Also I am able to get my submodule jacoc report run independently and get a coverage report for it. however when I run the jacocoreporttask in main module, it doesn't include submodule packages in it?

Comment: Same here, I'm only seeing the coverage reports for my individual modules. Did anyone get this to work?

Comment: In Project  build.gradle under 

 sourceDirectories ,
 classDirectories,
 executionData 

mention your own module name

Eg tasks.getByPath("<<Module Name>>:jacocoTestReport")

After this you will get both .. 
under main App complete coverage report and
 in each module module wise coverage report.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `getByPath` You can also use variables to reach different modules the build.gradle itself e.g `$buildDir` will take you to current module `build` folder.

Secondly, `$project.projectDir.parent` will take to parent project. Example `$project.projectDir.parent/<sub-project-name>/outputs/code-coverage/connected/coverage.ec`

You can use your sub project name : `gcm_demo, googleservices or networkcommunication`
as `$project.projectDir.parent/gcm_demo/outputs/code-coverage/connected/coverage.ec`

Note: make sure you use right file `coverage.ec` OR `coverage.exec` check whats being generated for you

To print all the paths, you can use the following task in the build.gradle:
run `gradle paths` as defined as

`task paths {
    println "Printing the current module build: $buildDir"
    println "Printing the module directory: $project.projectDir"
    println "Printing the parent module: $project.projectDir.parent"
}`

This will help you play with directories and file folders in the multi-module android projects. Problem for me was not able reach to the right folders and file directories from the sub-module `build.gradle`